# Semantic dropdown ui

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

Hi I am using Semantic Dropdown UI(https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#search-in-menu) and I was looking for a way to make searchable dropdown. They have that kind of feature but the problem is its not a full text search. It only allows you to search for the start strings.

On page try to look for the "Multiple Search Selection".

I search for "A"
[image]

When I search for "L" I was hoping that "Alabama" "Alaska" will still show up because they have "L"
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize it with the `fullTextSearch` option.

```
$('.ui.dropdown')
  .dropdown({
    fullTextSearch: true
});
```

As documented [here](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#additional-settings).

Comment: Thanks I was looking for that